# Main thread blocking on scroll and Kingfisher setting the image

Tags: ios, swift, kingfisher

I've been running down slow scroll performance and I've noticed that when I scroll and `setImage` gets called with non-cached images, the performance lags while the download happens.

```
if let imageURL = URL(string: presentable.imageUrl) {
    let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: imageURL)
    photoView.kf.setImage(with: resource, options: [.transition(.fade(0.2))])
}
```

My understanding is that Kingfisher downloads these on a background thread and then displays them on the main thread but the main thread seems to be temporarily blocked. Removing the `.transition` doesn't help the situation.

Any ideas on how to improve my scroll performance? Thanks

Comment: The scrolling stutters while the image loads in and then resumes. I'm just using KF's out of the box implementation for setImage, nothing custom

Comment: And is the image appropriately sized for the image view or is it much larger? I could imagine that could cause some slight stuttering...

Comment: It's likely larger. I can't control the image sizing, it's user-generated content

Comment: Yeah, but you could resize in the background. But I’d be surprised that KingFisher’s download is causing the hitch because that’s its whole _raison d’être._

Comment: That was my thinking. Let me try resizing first and then giving it to KF

Comment: KF has `backgroundDecode` option. Try it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When the images are larger than the image view, iOS needs to manipulate large `UIImage` objects, which can cause observable stuttering in the UI. You can prevent that problem by resizing the images before using them.

Fortunately, Kingfisher has a processor that can resize these (in a background thread) for you. As the [Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher/wiki/Cheat-Sheet#using-downsamplingimageprocessor-for-high-resolution-images) says:

> #### Using `DownsamplingImageProcessor` for high resolution images
>
> Think about the case we want to show some large images in a table view or a collection view. In the ideal world, we expect to get smaller thumbnails for them, to reduce downloading time and memory use. But in the real world, maybe your server doesn't prepare such a thumbnail version for you. The newly added `DownsamplingImageProcessor` rescues [sic]. It downsamples the high-resolution images to a certain size before loading to memory:
>
> ```
> imageView.kf.setImage(
>     with: resource,
>     placeholder: placeholderImage,
>     options: [
>         .processor(DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: imageView.size)),
>         .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
>         .cacheOriginalImage
>     ])
> ```
>
> Typically, `DownsamplingImageProcessor` is used with `.scaleFactor` and `.cacheOriginalImage`. It provides a reasonable image pixel scale for your UI, and prevent future downloading by caching the original high-resolution image.

I created a little test with small images and confirmed that it was silky smooth, but when I used large images, I experienced stuttering in the scrolling behavior. But when I added this `DownsamplingImageProcessor` in the large image scenario, it was silky smooth again.

Comment: This was true in my case... we should not load images larger than container.

Comment: Yep, we shouldn't load images larger than the container times the scale for that device (e.g. a 100×100 pt image view on a 3× device, should use images that are 300×300 px).

Comment: Also content mode matters sometimes, check my answer...

Answer (score 0):

> Updating
>
> ```
> self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
> ```
>
> to
>
> ```
> self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
> ```
>
> did the trick for me.

I have embedded `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`. Each `UICollectionViewCell` has an image view which loads image from URL using Kingfisher. My table view scrolling was a lot jerky and I tried different things including not to bind model and setting data to each cell. But nothing made any difference whatsoever. Once I changed content mode of image view, it is now scrolling very smoothly.

As per Rob's answer, it is also possible that setting mode to `.scaleAspectFill` might be required to do some processing even-though the image size is smaller (even 480 x 320 in my case). After updating mode to `.scaleAspectFit`, now its scrolling smoothly even for large-sized images.

Comment: Any ideas _why_ it helped?